# How to transfer files over bluetooth?

Tags: networking, bluetooth

How can I connect my mobile phone and Lubuntu 11.10 laptop over bluetooth so that I can transfer files between them?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply try starting the `bluetooth-applet` (maybe you need install it first) or the `bluetooth-wizard` and follow the on-screen guide.

(I am not 100% sure about the names as I am currently not at my linux machine - just type bluetooth in a bash-shell and hit tab for auto-completion to see possible matches.)

Comment: I tried `bluetooth-applet`, it's running but I can't see it, so I started `bluetooth-wizard` and it ended in step two `searching device`.

Comment: Maybe you can run the commands from the shell - this way you can see the output produced by the various tools. Moreover it might help to know what laptop or bluetooth dongle you have.

Comment: shell gives no feedback. Laptop is `Acer Travelmate 4002wlmi`. I dont' have bluetooth dongle it's integrated in the laptop.

Comment: According to the supported hardware https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportMachinesLaptopsAcer there seem to be no known problems with the bluetooth of your laptop - did you make sure that you turned it on via a bluetooth button on your laptop (if one exists)?

Comment: Yes, there is a button on the front, I pressed it a few times. `bluetooth-wizard` is still searching (step 2) and nothing is found.